# Debian Lost filesystem. Corrupted filesystem

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, boot, ext4

I have a file system bug/error.
My dedicated server cannot start.
OVH started my dedicated server in rescue mode, and:

```
root@rescue:~# parted /dev/sda 'print'
Model: ATA SAMSUNG MZ7LM240 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  240GB  240GB  primary                  boot
 2      240GB   240GB  536MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

So the problem, don't have file system in sda, and in sdb.

All data very-very important, so I must save them.
Please, help me, how can I create a file system in the disks, and restore everything?

I tried testdisk command, but i could not restore the file system.

When I try mount i got this message:

```
root@rescue:/mnt# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'

root@rescue:/mnt# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

And the fdisk write this:

```
root@rescue:/mnt# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc6522a8b

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 467810303 467808256 223.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       467810304 468856831   1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa398617a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         4096 467810303 467806208 223.1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       467810304 468856831   1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/md1: 446.1 GiB, 479033556992 bytes, 935612416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes

root@rescue:~# mount /dev/md1 /mnt/
mount: /dev/md1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/md1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/md1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

When I check dmesg:

```
root@rescue:~# dmesg | tail
[    8.724614]  md1: unknown partition table
[   10.430793] systemd-journald[389]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   18.468492] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   18.468494] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth1
[  492.873958] nf_conntrack: automatic helper assignment is deprecated and it will be removed soon. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
[  492.942832] ip_set: protocol 6
[  517.742940] ip_set: protocol 6
[ 1599.096427] EXT4-fs (md1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1602.001332] EXT4-fs (md1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 3396.499044] ip_set: protocol 6
```

I got e-mail from OVH:

> Here are the details of this operation: Diagnosis interface boot
>   (rescue) Date 2016-08-11 19:55:22, elyess H made Diagnosis interface
>   boot (rescue):  Here are the details of the operation performed: The
>   server gets stuck during the boot phase, with the message: (error:
>   unknowk filesystem) A restart on the standard OVH kernel ('netboot')
>   does not correct the situation.
>
> Actions: Rebooting the server to "rescue" mode (Linux)
>
> result: Boot OK. Rescue mode accessible.
>
> recommendations: Configuration / error to be corrected by the customer

**So the PROBLEM:** I lost my filesystem, and I cannot start, and I cannot mount the disk.
I have RAID-1 in the dedicated server, but I cannot mount /dev/md1.

How can I restore the file system? How can I mount the disk? How can I start the system? I think if I solve the filesystem, i will can start the system.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Easy - build the server from scratch and restore your last backup.

Comment: Paste cat /proc/mdstat output

Comment: root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md1 : active raid0 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      467806208 blocks 512k chunks

unused devices: <none>

Comment: @Chopper3 I don't really understand what did you mean. So... How can I fix my problem?

Comment: By restoring from your last backup

Comment: I had RAID-1 so I did not have any backup. I must somehow restore the filesystem.

Comment: "I had RAID-1 so I did not have an backup" - Serverfault, as we make clear when you sign up, is a site for professional sysadmins, who take backups - RAID is not a backup.

Comment: Yes I know. But I did not have backup. Unfortunatelly... But I must solve the problem. And it is the past, now i sould solve it. And please help :-(

Comment: In that case, I'd Google for "data recovery <your location>" and see what results you have. You could also try and boot from a linux live cd and see if any of the disks can be read that way.

Comment: I can boot with OVH rescue mode, but I cannot mount the disks.

Comment: Have you tried restoring from your latest backup?

Comment: My last backup is too old. I need these datas.

Comment: It's important that you understand that what you've done is staggeringly unprofessional and you've then come a place specifically for professionals to ask for hep - imagine if you'd walked into a airline pilot lounge and said "I appear to have sawn my plane's wings off - halp!"

Comment: according to mdstat you have raid 0 not raid 1. so it is no wonder you cannot access data on a single disk.

Comment: you can also see that md1 (the raid 0 devices) is double the size of your disks.

Comment: try kpartx -l /dev/md1 from the rescue system and paste output

Comment: please post the kpartx -l /dev/md1 output.

Comment: the do kpartx -a /dev/md1 and try mounting /dev/mapper/md1p1 or something like that.

Comment: kpartx -l /dev/md1    - no output

Comment: look if there is a /dev/mapper/md1p1 or similar.

Comment: what do you remember from the server was it one big filesystem or several?

Comment: what filesysrem was there ext3 ext4 xfs or other?

Comment: root@rescue:~# kpartx -l /dev/mapper/md1
failed to stat() /dev/mapper/md1

Comment: I don't remember, but I think it was ext4. Or maybe ext3, but I really think it was ext4.

Comment: what happened to the server before the problem?

Comment: ok do fsck.ext .

Comment: sorry fsck.ext4 /dev/md1

Comment: I did reboot the system, and after reboot it doesn't start.

Comment: Hmm. If i run fsck.ext4 /dev/md1 I got a long message.

Comment: e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP needs tech support and not Q&A.

Comment: I agree, he's also clearly unskilled and need access to better skills.

Comment: Ofc -.- it was help me -.-

Comment: First of all - RAID-0 is no substitute for backup. Secondly your partition tables only indicate a single RAID partition. If you are lucky then all you need to do is to fix the partition type and reassemble the array. But from the mdstat output I cannot figure out how many members were in that RAID and how many were left at reassembly time. On my systems mdstat has more useful information looking like this `2855955264 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]` - notice the counts and state of each member.

Answer (score 5):

In short way, you're in serious troubles. From mdstat you posted as comment, I can see you have RAID-0, not RAID-1 configuration, see:

> root@rescue:~# cat /proc/mdstat Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty] md1 : active **raid0** sda1[0] sdb1[1] 467806208 blocks 512k chunks unused devices:

Raid-0 is stripped raid - you're using all capacity of all of your drives and data are saved across all disks, but you have no redundancy for case of failing device.

And this is what happened to your server. One of your disks failed. It is common thing in server environment. But because you have only RAID-0 configuration, you're screw and all of your data are lost.

Now it depends on value of data saved on your server. You can try to talk with OVH to power off your server, take those drives out and send it to some company specialized to rescue data from failed drives. It is expensive service and you have no guarantee they will restore 100% of your data. It will definitely take days or weeks to restore it and your server will be offline for this time.

Another way is to restore your backups and accept damage.

No another way here, I'm sorry.

Comment: what makes you think one disk failed?

Answer (score -4):

ok try the fsck.ext4 with the alternate superblock like sugested.

Comment: ok try the alternate superblock with fsck as sugested.

Comment: I tied alternate superblock , but i got same message.

Comment: ok this is bad. get images of both disks with dd over ssh. ssh root@rescuesystem dd if=

Comment: ssh root@rescue dd if=/dev/sfa

Comment: will try again in bout 2 hours

Comment: I ran this command: mkfs.ext4 /dev/md1
And after I mounted with: mount /dev/md1 /mnt

But in the /mnt directory is empty (only an empty lost+found directory).

I didn't reboot the system (yet). What is the next step?

Comment: @MaróthyZsolt you need to back away from the keyboard, you're making matters much much worse.

Comment: @MaróthyZsolt And that's why you should have hired a professional to help you. That command may just have cost you the last tiny chance of recovering anything.